# Derivative of a function to original function without integration

Tags: calculus

I am working on a Calculus assignment and we were given this question:

```
If $f'(x)=5^{2x-1}$ what is $f(x)$?
```

We have not covered integration or anti-derivatives yet, and unfortunately I am stuck on the problem and have been for about 10 minutes.

How would I go about solving this problem?

Comment: do you know a function whose derivative is $e^x$? how about a function whose derivative is something like $25^x$?

Comment: Don't worry, your problem is everyone's problem :) There is no universal way to "antiderive", you kind of just try different strategies. Of course after a while one begins to notice certain classes of functions and can try to "antiderive" them in general, but there's no way to do it for *any* function. Fortunately this kind of exponential falls into one of these classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can guess the result and then verify it. Assume that $a, b, c, d$ are constants and calculate the derivative of $f(x) = a b^{c x - d}$. Then fix the constants to match your problem.

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x) = 5^{2x-1}  \Rightarrow f'(x) = e^{({2x-1})ln(5)} \Rightarrow  f(x) = \frac {1}{2ln(5)}e^{({2x-1)}ln(5)}  + Constant \Rightarrow f(x) = \frac {1}{2ln(5)}5^{2x-1}  + Constant$$

Comment: The OP is trying to solve the problem without integration.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have learned, you may use the series expansion $$e^{at}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a^nt^n}{n!}$$ about $t=0$. Using $f'(x)=5^{2x-1}=e^{(2x-1)\ln 5}=\frac{1}{5}e^{(2\ln 5)x}$, $f''(x)=\frac{2\ln 5}{5}e^{(2\ln 5)x}$, $f'''(x)=\frac{(2\ln 5)^2}{5}e^{(2\ln 5)x}$, . . ., $f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(2\ln 5)^{n-1}}{5}e^{(2\ln 5)x}$, we have
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2+\frac{f'''(0)}{3!}x^3+\cdots+\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}x^n+\cdots $$
$$f(x)=f(0)+\frac{1}{5}x+\frac{2\ln 5}{2!5}x^2+\frac{2\ln 5}{3!5}x^3+\cdots+\frac{(2\ln 5)^{n-1}}{n!5}x^n+\cdots $$
$$f(x)=f(0)-\frac{1}{5(2\ln 5)}+\frac{1}{5(2\ln 5)}\bigg[1+(2\ln 5)x+\frac{(2\ln 5)^2}{2!}x^2+\frac{(2\ln 5)^3}{3!}x^3+\cdots+\frac{(2\ln 5)^{n}}{n!}x^n+\cdots \bigg].$$ Using the above expansion with $a=2\ln 5$ we get 
$$f(x)=f(0)-\frac{1}{5(2\ln 5)}+\frac{1}{5(2\ln 5)}e^{(2\ln 5)x}=f(0)-\frac{1}{5(2\ln 5)}+\frac{1}{2\ln 5}5^{2x-1}.$$